# Define tuple recursively

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am using `GCC8.2` and I would like to define a hierarchical tuple like this:

```cpp
std::tuple<std::array<double,N>,
           std::array<double,N/2>,
           std::array<double,N/4>,
           ...,
           std::array<double,2> > v ;
```

And then I have an algorithm to fill those arrays with the following specification:

```cpp
template <int N>
std::array<double,N> get_array()
```

How can I write a generic algorithm to declare the tuple and fill it at compile time for any `N`?

Comment: Why do you need a `variant`?

Comment: @Evg Now that you say it, I could use a tuple. But the question still stands.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True, but doing that would be so ugly. There must be a way to do this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're right, my bad. I changed to `std::tuple`

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to initialize the `std::tuple` with the return value of `get_array()`

Comment: The last edit (`get_array`)  doesn't improve the question. Why would `get_array` need that tuple? It only returns the first element of the tuple.

Comment: @MSalters `get_array` is just a generic template function that has been given to me to obtain the arrays of any size I want. I want to use the function to fill the tuple, that's all.

Comment: Is the 4th element N/8 or N/6? What if N is 3 (so it does not end with `<double, 2>`)? Is `v` a global variable so that `get_array` is able to access `v`? If it is, what is `N` in the type of `v`? Do you mean `v` is a variable template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without recursion, you might do something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::array<double, N> get_array() { return {{}}; }

namespace detail
{

    constexpr std::size_t log2(std::size_t n)
    {
        std::size_t res = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            n /= 2;
            ++res;
        }
        return res;
    }

    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ...Is>
    auto make_array_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return make_tuple(get_array<(N >> Is)>()...);
    }

}

template <std::size_t N>
auto make_array_tuple()
{
    return detail::make_array_tuple_impl<N>(std::make_index_sequence<detail::log2(N) - 1>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/268eb4e7c1917f31)

Answer (score 3):

This feels a bit involved, maybe there's a simpler solution.

```
// Pack of values
template <auto...>
struct vpack { };

// Concatenating two packs
template <class, class>
struct vpack_cat_;

template <auto... lhs, auto... rhs>
struct vpack_cat_<vpack<lhs...>, vpack<rhs...>> {
    using type = vpack<lhs..., rhs...>;
};

template <class Lhs, class Rhs>
using vpack_cat = typename vpack_cat_<Lhs, Rhs>::type;

// Building a decreasing exp scale...
template <int N>
struct exp_scale_ {
    using type = vpack_cat<
        vpack<N>,
        typename exp_scale_<N / 2>::type
    >;
};

// ... stopping at 2
template <>
struct exp_scale_<2> {
    using type = vpack<2>;
};

template <int N>
using exp_scale = typename exp_scale_<N>::type;

// Building the tuple's type from the scale
template <class ScalePack>
struct exp_tuple_;

template <auto... Scale>
struct exp_tuple_<vpack<Scale...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<std::array<double, Scale>...>;
};

template <class Scale>
using exp_tuple = typename exp_tuple_<Scale>::type;

// The known get_array() function
template <int N>
std::array<double,N> get_array() { return {}; }

// Initializing the tuple
template <auto... Scale>
auto get_tuple(vpack<Scale...>) {
    return exp_tuple<vpack<Scale...>>{
        get_array<Scale>()...
    };
}

template <int N>
auto get_tuple() {
    return get_tuple(exp_scale<N>{});
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e6527705bac3064)

Comment: Unfortunately the OP has changed the question since you started working on this.  Now they want a tuple of all the arrays, instead of a variant.

Comment: @NathanOliver well that's just a single-word replacement, no fuss.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I am very sorry about that, I got it wrong.

Comment: *"maybe there's a simpler solution"*, without recursion, and `std::index_sequence` and a `constexpr` `log2` we can.

Comment: @Jarod42 for some reason I forgot that `constexpr` functions can actually be sane now. Welp.

Comment: @Jarod42 Without recursion? I'm VERY interested in it then. Could you elaborate? I'm using GCC8.2 to profit from the last standard developments.

Comment: @Astor Jarod is just nagging me, he already posted his answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your sequence in

```
std::tuple<std::array<double,N>,
           std::array<double,N/2>,
           std::array<double,N/4>,
           ...,
           std::array<double,2> > v ;
```

ends with `2`?

Supposing that you want to end with `2` or `1`, I suppose you can use the following custom type traits to get the wanted index sequence

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct divSequence : public divSequence<(N>>1u), Is..., (N>>1u)>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct divSequence<2u, Is...> : public std::index_sequence<Is...>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct divSequence<1u, Is...> : public std::index_sequence<Is...>
 { };
```

So you only need the following make function (with helper)

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::tuple<std::array<double, Is>...>
   getDivTupleHelper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return { get_array<Is>()... }; }

template <std::size_t N>
auto getDivTuple ()
 { return getDivTupleHelper(divSequence<N>{}); }
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N>
std::array<double,N> get_array ()
 { return {{ }}; }

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct divSequence : public divSequence<(N>>1u), Is..., (N>>1u)>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct divSequence<2u, Is...> : public std::index_sequence<Is...>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct divSequence<1u, Is...> : public std::index_sequence<Is...>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::tuple<std::array<double, Is>...>
   getDivTupleHelper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return { get_array<Is>()... }; }

template <std::size_t N>
auto getDivTuple ()
 { return getDivTupleHelper(divSequence<N>{}); }


int main ()
 {
   using t0 = decltype( getDivTuple<15u>() );
   using t1 = std::tuple<std::array<double, 7u>,
                         std::array<double, 3u>,
                         std::array<double, 1u>>;
   using t2 = decltype( getDivTuple<16u>() );
   using t3 = std::tuple<std::array<double, 8u>,
                         std::array<double, 4u>,
                         std::array<double, 2u>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<t0, t1>::value, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<t2, t3>::value, "!");
 }
```

If you need a C++11 solution... well... instead of `std::index_sequence` you can use a custom trivial substitute as

```
template <std::size_t ...>
struct myIndexSequence
 { }
```

and you need rewrite `getDivTuple()` to explicit the return type using `decltype()`; something as

```
template <std::size_t N>
decltype(getDivTupleHelper(divSequence<N>{})) getDivTuple ()
 { return getDivTupleHelper(divSequence<N>{}); }
```